# How does $4(1+2+...+(n-1))$ equal $4(n-1)n/2$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I would like some help in understanding this sequence:

$$1 + 4(1+2+...+(n-1)) = 1 + 4(n-1)\frac{n}{2}$$

How does $4(1+2+...+(n-1))$ equal $4(n-1)n/2$?

This is related to the sum of the first positive integers formula:

$$(n+1)n/2 = 1+2+...+(n-1)+n$$ But I don't understand why it's $(n-1)$ instead of $(n+1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$1+\ldots +(n-1)+n =\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\implies 1+\ldots +(n-1)=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-n=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

It looks as if you are aware of the formula
$$1+2+3+\cdots+m=\frac{m(m+1)}{2}$$
for the sum of the first $m$ positive integers.

Put $m=n-1$. We get $\dfrac{(n-1)(n)}{2}$.

Comment: yes actually it  does not change anything if  $n$ is changed by $m-1$  or $m-k$

Answer (score 1):

You have 
$$
1 + 4 (1 + 2 + \ldots (n - 1)) 
  = 1 + 4 \cdot \frac{n (n - 1)}{2}
  = 1 + 2 n (n - 1)
  = 2 n^2 - 2 n + 1
$$
Use the formula for the sum of the first integers for $n - 1$, not for $n$.